# String iterator and passing characters to another methods

Tags: c++, string, enums

I have a little sink the fleet program, where I have a function which takes string as input and then creates ships for the player.

The input string format is always B-A3-S, which means Shiptype is Battleship (B), starting from coordinate A3 to the south (S). There can be multiple coordinates in the same string, and there is always at least one space between them, for example: B-A3-S C-D8-N. Types are enumerated values (Battleship, Destroyer, Cruiser, Submarine).

I thought I could use iterator to loop through the string characters one by one and pass current character to the function that returns ShipType. But I keep getting error and exception EXCEPTION_WRONG_SHIP_TYPE;

I'm just learning how to use pointers and classes, so I'm not sure where my problem is.

Player Class method:

```
void Player::addShips(string ships) {
    string::iterator it; //iterator to go through string
    //ship attributes 
    ShipType type;
    Coordinate pos; 
    Orientation o;

    for (it = ships.begin(); it != ships.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it == ships.at(0) && isalpha(ships[*it])) || (isalpha(ships[*it]) && isspace(ships[*it-1]))) { 
            type = Ship::typeFromChar(ships[*it]);  
        } else if (ships[*it] == '-') {
         ...//more conditions for different situations
        } 
    }
}
```

Class Ship has method

```
ShipType Ship::typeFromChar(char type) {
    ShipType st;
    if (type == 'B') { 
        st = BATTLESHIP;
    } else if (type == 'D') {
        st = DESTROYER;
    } else if (type == 'C') {
        st = CRUISE;
    } else if (type == 'S') {
        st = SUBMARINE;
    } else { 
        throw EXCEPTION_WRONG_SHIP_TYPE; //
    }
    return st;
}
```

And from main, the addShips() is called like this:

```
Player player1("Jack");
try {
        string ships="B-B3-E S-J10-N   C-D7-W  D-A1-S";
        player1.addShips(ships);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Util::error(ERR_SHIPS);
        Util::debug(e);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ships[*it]` is wrong. `it` is an iterator, not an index. And dereferencing it returns the current character in the string, not an index into the string.

Just use `it` by itself, eg:

```
void Player::addShips(string ships) {
    string::iterator it; //iterator to go through string
    //ship attributes 
    ShipType type;
    Coordinate pos; 
    Orientation o;

    for (it = ships.begin(); it != ships.end(); ++it) {
        if ((it == ships.begin() && isalpha(*it)) || (isalpha(*it) && isspace(*(it-1)))) { 
            type = Ship::typeFromChar(*it);
        } else if (*it == '-') {
         ...//more conditions for different situations
        } 
    }
}
```

That being said, a much cleaner way to parse out the values from your input `string` would be to use `istringstream` to read each coordinate separated by whitespace, and use `std::sscanf()` to parse the individual components of each coordinate, eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void Player::addShips(string ships) {
    istringstream iss(ships);
    string ship;
    while (iss >> ship) {
        char cType, cCoord[3], cOrientation;
        if (sscanf(ship.c_str(), "%c-%2s-%c", &cType, cCoord, &cOrientation) == 3)
        {
            ShipType type = Ship::typeFromChar(cType);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, using sscanf() makes sense here. If the middle part of the each ship string can hold 2 or 3 values (the column number can be more than 9, for example D-A45-E), can I just left that 2 out? so that the format would be "%c-%s-%c"?

Comment: Leaving off the number altogether from `%s` opens the code up to a potential buffer overflow. But you can *increase* the number as needed to allow for larger values, eg: `char cCoord[4]; sscanf(ship.c_str(), "...-%3s-...", ... , cCoord, ...)` On the other hand, if the middle part is *always* a letter and a number, then consider using `%c%d` instead, eg: `char cCoord, int numCoord; sscanf(ship.c_str(), "...-%c%d-...", ... , &cCoord, &numCoord, ...)`